Setting partition type to Ox7
I have a dual boot system:  Fedora, Windows 11.  Separate hard drives.  I can no longer boot to Windows from GRUB2 menu.  Receive message "Setting partition type to Ox7."  I've tried to boot directly through UEFI.  No luck.  Is this a GRUB issue?  Suggestions?

Welcome. What research have you done and what have you tried so far prior to asking this question here?

I'm not particularly adept at this.  What would you suggest I research?  I've Googled the problem, but haven't found a solution particular to this problem.

I may have solved this issue, but not completely comfortable with it, yet.  Ran Windows 11 Repair Disc which indicated that it could not fix my problem, but then it did.   I think.  I still get the "Setting partition type to Ox7" message, before Windows boots.  Never saw that before.  Windows now boots, so I'm content.

Probably would help if you could post the commands grub executes when booting Windows.
